# Window screen crashes on python using pygame and uagame

Tags: python-3.x

It is not responding when after the Hunting in draw_string word crashes not responding the screen. It doesn't continue until the end of the line. Is there a fix? I also use the os and sys for not responding. It doesn't seem to work. I don't know if there is also a problem with the version of python.

```
from uagame import Window
from time import sleep 
import os
import sys

window = Window("Hacking",600 ,500)
window.set_font_size(18)
window.set_font_color('green')
window.set_bg_color('black')
window.update()
line_y = 0
height = window.get_font_height()
window.draw_string('DEBUG MODE' , 0 , line_y)
window.update()
sleep(0.3)

line_y = line_y + height
window.draw_string('1 attempt(s) Left ',0,line_y)
window.update()
sleep(0.5)

line_y = line_y + height
window.draw_string('' , 0 , line_y)
window.update()
sleep(0.5)


line_y = line_y + height
window.draw_string('PROVIDE' , 0 , line_y)
window.update()
sleep(0.5)


line_y = line_y + height
window.draw_string('SETTING' , 0 , line_y)
window.update()
sleep(0.5)

line_y = line_y + height
window.draw_string('CANTINA' , 0 , line_y)
window.update()
sleep(0.5)

line_y = line_y + height
window.draw_string('CUTTING' , 0 , line_y)
window.update()
sleep(0.5) 

line_y = line_y + height
window.draw_string('HUNTERS' , 0 , line_y)
window.update()
sleep(0.5) 

line_y = line_y + height
window.draw_string('SURVIVE' , 0 , line_y)
window.update()
sleep(0.5) 

line_y = line_y + height
window.draw_string('HEARING' , 0 , line_y)
window.update()
sleep(0.3) 

line_y = line_y + height
window.draw_string('HUNTING' , 0 , line_y)
window.update()
sleep(0.3) 

line_y = line_y + height
window.draw_string('REALIZE' , 0 , line_y)
window.update()
sleep(0.3) 

line_y = line_y + height
window.draw_string('NOTHING' , 0 , line_y)
window.update()
sleep(0.5) 

line_y = line_y + height
window.draw_string('OVERLAP' , 0 , line_y)
window.update()
sleep(0.5) 

line_y = line_y + height
window.draw_string('FINDING' , 0 , line_y)
window.update()
sleep(0.5) 

line_y = line_y + height
window.draw_string('PUTTING' , 0 , line_y)
window.update()
sleep(0.5)
line_y = line_y + height
window.draw_string('' , 0 , line_y)
window.update()
sleep(0.3)
line_y = line_y + height
window.draw_string("Enter password" , 0 , line_y)
window.update()
sleep(0.3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't code the rest of the problem.
The problem is to display a column of 13 passwords and promoting the user to enter any one among them. After that the another window is opened and ,

1. Your guess is displayed
2. Shows " login failure - terminal locked "
3. Displays " please contact an administrator"
4. Displays " press enter to exit"
5. When you press the enter key the window closes

The rest of the code also includes some functions inorder to display the outputs at the centre of the window according to the string height and length.

Try to code the rest of the code. Keep going.